# customise shiny R data tables

Tags: css, r, datatable, shiny

Is it possible to apply customize css file to change appearance of dataTable in R Shiny? I tried applying

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(theme = "bootstrap.css",
```

at the beginning but it does not effect the row colour of the table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first create a **'www'** directory inside your app directory. Download `"bootstrap.css"` and put it in there.

Compile and run!

It must work.